# How make backward compatibility of AFnetworking library

Tags: ios, ios5, ios7, xcode5, afnetworking-2

My app deployment target is ios5. and I downloaded Afnetworking 2.0 library. but this causes error like **"Property with 'retain(or strong)' attribute must be of object type"**

1. Please tell me in details how to remove that error.I googled but
   some developer posted change deployment target from ion to ios6 .
   this is fine but I want app on iOS 5 also.
2. soppose I have developer on app on ios5 . I want support in ios7 now.how manage like remove deprecated method and add new method in development .after all that new app will run on iOS 5 . or I need to create 2 build for both.

Please tell me all in details and any related information which is need to consideration in development.
Thanks...........

Comment: AFNetworking 2.0 is for iOS 6 and higher, if you need to support iOS 5 download AFnetworking 1.1

Comment: Thanks, if i use Afnetworking 1.1 then it will work on iOS 6,ios7 or not

Comment: Ofcourse why should it not? You just can't use any iOS 7 only features since they are implement in AFNetworking 2 only.